# Find the 5 sets of 6 items with the highest sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have a list of percentages. It doesn't matter what they represent at the moment, so let's just leave it aside.

The list looks something like this:
`[19.39%,21.52%,7.32%,14.81%,5.75%,1.92%,15.00%,18.18%,6.82%,15.73%,8.33%,13.00%,1.01%,6.76%,4.82%,5.81%,3.37%,19.54%,11.54%,14.95%,13.92%,10.00%,19.00%,1.25%,10.48%,2.27%,25.61%,11.01%,7.32%,13.79%,10.71%,14.94%,13.73%,5.62%,3.75%,7.50%,7.62%]`

I would like to get the cell (location) of the 5 sets of 6 that their sum is the highest, but not larger than 100%.

For instance if the first 6 items in the list had a sum of 100%,
they would be set1 and the return value would be `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`.
Set 2 can use the same values but with at least one difference: `[0,1,2,3,4,6]`

It's OK for a set's sum to be smaller than 100% as long as it is one of the top 5 sums.

Now I know I can iterate over the list over and over looking for the highest number first then adding a number and checking if the sum is not over 100% each time, but that is terrible way to do it.

I am looking for some way to work with sets.

Comment: Is what you have a single string (that *looks* like a list) or is it an actual list, containing strings?

Comment: I don't think approaching this from the angle of sets/subsets of the entire list is the correct approach. Rather, you should look at the *sequence* of the highest numbers and *their* combinations. E.g. the largest sum across the list is just the sum of the 5 largest numbers; there is no need to look at all subsets.

Comment: @ mkrieger1 its an actual list
@ MisterMiyagi that what i thought as i said in the post but that seems a little bulky , im wondering if there is a better way

Comment: And it's another good point i can't assume there are no duplications if there is a duplication that i need 10 sets where one starts with cell 0 and the second starts with cell N

Comment: Better way than what? "The h highest numbers out of n" is an n log(n) + h problem (sort and slice). Looking at subsets is h^n, which is *much* worse.

Comment: "i can't assume there are no duplications" Then what does it mean to form sums over sets? Sets don't have duplicates. If any *combination* involving duplicates is the highest, would that be viable at all, one set, or as many sets as there are duplicates?

Comment: hmmm , good point i guess im looking at the problem wrong
i can make sets then extract all the cell numbers that contain this sets

Comment: in any case you are saying that its far more affective to just solve it in the first way i did

Comment: Sorry i accidently deleted the question, @mistermiyagi , so how would you go about solving it ?
2 for loops to iterate over the list sum all combinations and then pick the biggest ones ?

Comment: "are saying that its far more affective to just solve it in the first way i did" No, since you are operating on the raw data in arbitrary order. *Sorting* and then finding the sets beginning at the largest numbers would be the most effective. Sorting is merely O(n log n) and one then has to look only at the first 7 numbers or so to construct the 5 largest sets of size 6.

Comment: ahh sorry i was not clear on that , yes obviously if im going at it with the standard way then sorting is a must

Comment: If you want to answer the question in an official way i would be happy to mark it as the answer

Comment: you know how sometimes you have grand ideas that do not actually have any merit in reality , this is the case here , i was going to create all sets of 6 then sort them by their sum and pick the closest ones but it seems redundant now

Comment: this was the way i thought to go about it with sets just fyi: 

list(map(set, itertools.combinations(precentage, 6)))
then run on each combo and sum it , check if it is below 100 and add it to a list with the sum as the first value then return a sorted list

but i can see now that its not a great way to go , it takes 2.5 seconds on average just to get all the combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the list of given data is 37. Out of them you should make 6-tuples which means 37C6 combinations, as a number 2'324'784. Then ordering and excluding tuples which sum is >100, finally take the 1st 5s.

```
import itertools as it

data = '19.39%,21.52%,7.32%,14.81%,5.75%,1.92%,15.00%,18.18%,6.82%,15.73%,8.33%,13.00%,1.01%,6.76%,4.82%,5.81%,3.37%,19.54%,11.54%,14.95%,13.92%,10.00%,19.00%,1.25%,10.48%,2.27%,25.61%,11.01%,7.32%,13.79%,10.71%,14.94%,13.73%,5.62%,3.75%,7.50%,7.62%'

data = data[:-1].split('%,')
data = map(float, data)
data = list(data)#[:10]     # for testing make a small slice!

data = dict(enumerate(data))

ordered_data = [p for p in sorted(it.combinations(data, 6), key=lambda x: sum(map(data.get, x)), reverse=True)]

filtered_data = [p for p in ordered_data if sum(map(data.get, p)) <= 100]
print(filtered_data[:5])
```

Output

```
[(0, 1, 3, 17, 27, 32), (0, 1, 7, 14, 24, 26), (0, 1, 8, 17, 22, 32), (0, 1, 9, 14, 17, 22), (0, 1, 11, 21, 24, 26)] # all 100%
```

Comment: Remark: all the 5 tuples above score 100% but there even more than 5 with 100%